# How could I initialize val object in the try catch block?

Tags: scala

I have this code in Scala, `a` object should be value not a variable, How can I initialize the `a` object in the try block?

```
object SomeObject {
  private val a : SomeClass

  try {
    a=someThing // this statement may throw an exception
  }
  catch {
    case ex:  Exception=> {
       ex.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What should the value of `a` be if the `try` fails?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato I will be null or something undefined. I just want to initialize them in the try catch, Because the assignment may throw an exception

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Like opening a file stream

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Scala tries to avoid undefined/null values. However, you can solve the problem by giving return values for the cases if the `try` fails and initializing `a` with the whole `try` expression:

```
private val a: SomeClass =
  try {
    someThing // this statement may throw an exception
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      ex.printStackTrace()
      someDefault
    }
  }
```

**Update:** In Scala it would be probably more idiomatic to use [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try) from `scala.util`:

```
val x : Int =
  Try({
    someThing
  }).recoverWith({
    // Just log the exception and keep it as a failure.
    case (ex: Throwable) => ex.printStackTrace; Failure(ex);
  }).getOrElse(1);
```

`Try` allows you to compose computations that can fail with an exception in various ways. For example, if you have two computations of type `Try` you can call

```
thing1.orElse(thing2).getOrElse(someDefault)
```

This runs `thing1` and returns its result, if it's successful. If it fails, it continues with `thing2`. If it fails too, returns `someDefault`. You can also use `recover` or `recoverWith` to recover from some exceptions using partial functions (and potentially reuse those partial functions).

Comment: I did not find Try in the scala.util package. What is your scala version?

Comment: `Try` is available since 2.10: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Try

Comment: Is it possible to omit the `.recoverWith()` and just put the `case (ex: Throwable) => ex.printStackTrace; Failure(ex);` inside the `.getOrElse()`?

Comment: @LXXIII `recoverWith` replaces `try/catch`, and handles an exception thrown in the `Try({...})` clause. You can't just put `case` into `getOrElse`. This function allows you to provide a default, but doesn't give you access to exceptione thrown in `Try`, if it fails.

Comment: "Try comes to the Scala standard library after years of use as an integral part of Twitter's stack." It's insanely cool that they include this kind of acknowledgement.

Answer (score 4):

Since in Scala blocks have return values, and the last expression is the return value per default, you can do this:

```
object SomeObject {
  private val a : SomeClass = { //this additional block not necessary, but added for clarity
      try {
        someThing // this statement may throw an exception
      }
      catch {
        case ex:  Exception=> {
           ex.printStackTrace()
           null
        }
      }
    }
}
```

. However, I have to add that this looks like you're trying to accomplish something potentially blowing up in your face later - you will need `null` checks in any code that uses the value.